# Can't read file larger than 2GB in Ubuntu 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, limit

**SOLVED**
@nsilent22, Thanks for your suggestion. Only change I made is in the seekg() function parameter.

```
ND_file.seekg( (long)(block_number)*DISK_BLOCK_SIZE );
ND_file.read((char*)(&count), sizeof(int));
```

**Original Post**

I know similar questions have been asked and answered earlier. Still need help for an existing program.

Hardware Spec : Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, ext4 file system

I have an old program for creating a disk based index. When the index file reaches to 2.1GB, following read() function inputs wrong value and the program aborts.

```
ND_file.seekg(block_number*DISK_BLOCK_SIZE);
ND_file.read((char*)(&count), sizeof(int));
```

Based on similar posts, I have put #define  _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64 at the beginning of each file.

Following is the make file:

```
GCC=g++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
NDT: main.o utility.o logClass.o
     g++ -g -o ndTree main.o utility.o logClass.o
     rm *.o
main.o: main.cpp config.h Box_queries.h Meta_entry.h Meta_node.h Dir_entry.h Dir_node.h Leaf_entry.h Leaf_node.h logClass.h ND_tree.h Node.h utility.h
     g++ -g -c main.cpp
utility.o: utility.cpp utility.h
     g++ -g -c utility.cpp
logClass.o: logClass.cpp logClass.h
     g++ -g -c logClass.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

@Updated

Portion of output log : Here Block-174 is called twice. In the first case, the read function input disk data correctly. However, in the last line, #Entries is 0 which is not right. And this happens when the block::524288 is assigned. Therefore, I guess read() and seekg() don't work properly.

```
Id       NewBlockId   ParentBlockId  #EntriesInBlock  Index #MaxEntries   
554192   524280       463255         149              61    255       
554193   524281       463255         149              75    255
554194   524282       497389         131              80    255
**554195     524283       174            250              26    255**
554196   524284       125426         142              77    255
554197   524285       223509         130             118    255
554198   524286       262212         136              72    255
554199   524287       224407         142             121    255
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
**554200     524288       174              0             227    255** Aborted (core dumped)
```

Should I need to use different functions for reading file contents? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why the previous answers were not helpful?

Comment: My operating system is 64 bit, file system ext4, off_t is also ok. Moreover, i explicitly defined -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64. Still got the same problem. So, I was wondering if the problem is with read() and seekg().

Comment: What type is `block_number` and `DISK_BLOCK_SIZE`?

Comment: const int DISK_BLOCK_SIZE; unsigned int block_number;

Comment: So do you think `unsigned int * int` implicitly cast to a signed 64-bit value may, perhaps cause a problem? And perhaps that using a `uint64_t` for at least one of those might solve that issue?

Answer (score 4):

Well the answer is simple. Basing on your comment:

> const int DISK_BLOCK_SIZE; unsigned int block_number;

both variables are of type `int` (one `unsigned`), so the computed value is... `int`.
And the size of `int` on 64-bit Ubuntu system is... 32 bits. On your 64-bit system compile this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 2000000000;
    int y = 4;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    printf("x * y = %d\n", x * y);
    printf("x * y = %ld\n", (long)(x * y));
    printf("x * y = %ld\n", (long)(x) * y);
    return 0;
}
```

and you'll see what you ought to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your suggestion definitely helps to solve another potential problem of my code. However, the original problem still persists. Please see the updated text for more detail.

Comment: You need to change your program to use `off_t` and `size_t` where appropriate.  Compile it with warnings enabled, and fix all the warnings about losing data from storing a result into a narrower type without a cast.  (I forget if there are such warnings, but hopefully).  Quick&dirty solution might be to change every int to long, if that doesn't affect any binary data it needs to read.

Comment: @user2185422: Block 524288 is exactly 0x80000 in hex. Multiply it by 4096 and you'll find out what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I tried your way. ND_file.seekg((long)(block_number*DISK_BLOCK_SIZE) ). But from the output, you can see the problem occurs when I tried to access block 174. For block 524283, this 174 gives the correct result. The read function multiplies parent block id with block size. My point is it might be the read() function. I am requesting for a library function which can handle any file size. Not sure if seekg() and read() can do that.

Comment: @user2185422: That's wrong way. Casting WHOLE operation to `long` changes nothing. And we were talking about row with NewBlockId equal to 524288.

Comment: so, I should try this ((long)(x) * y)?

Comment: If you'd be so kind ;)